# ASSIST WITH RUBY CODE TO GET "user", "domain" and "domain.com" from email string user@domain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please I need help with something like substring of PHP for Ruby that can make me get "user" "domain" and "domain.com" in this output email "user@domain.com"

e.g john@dortmund.com

Let say I have %3% in my line of code to call user the result will be = "john".

Let say I have %2% in my line of code to call domainname the result will be = "dortmund".

Let say I have %1% in my line of code to call domain.com the result will be = "dortmund.com"

I have been cracking my head but couldn't get it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split is your friend!

```
email.split(/[@,.]/)
 => ["user", "domain", "com"]
```

from there you can manipulate the array to get the desired outputs. For example:

```
email.split(/[@,.]/).last(2).join('.')
 => "domain.com"
```

Some emails can have multiple dots in them and you may want to handle this:

```
email = "some.thing@email.com"
email.split(/(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)/).drop(1)
 => ["some.thing", "email", "com"]
```

Comment: thank you instead i used "rpartition" and fixed it, but now it's conflicting with the other 3, i can only use it one at a time, instead of being able to use the whole 4 functions at once see please https://ghostbin.co/paste/tmrou/raw
can't use %0% %1% %2% at a time code only works one at a time please help

Comment: Help please @benjessop

Comment: @Swit.stellz `"some.thing@email.com".rpartition('@')
 => ["some.thing", "@", "email.com"] ` is that what you are looking for?

Comment: no i mean .rpartition works perfectly but i mean implementing it inside my mailer project i already have it was conflicting with the other 3, see this https://ghostbin.co/paste/tmrou/raw or i can send u the full zip to see where my mistake is? @benjessop